# JNI native method missing but no build error

Tags: android-studio, java-native-interface, android-build, android-lint

In MyClass.java I have

```
package com.example.foo;
public class MyClass {
    public native void MyMethod();
```

and in MyClass.cpp I have

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL xJava_com_example_foo_MyClass_MyMethod(JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz)
{
    blah blah blah
}
```

Elsewhere in the Java code there's a call `MyMethod();`  However, as the eagle-eyed amongst you will have spotted, I've accidentally splatted an "x" at the start of my native method name, and this causes an uncaught exception runtime error `No implementation found for void com.example.foo.MyClass.MyMethod()`.  Is there some linty magic I can turn on that checks whether all my `public native` methods have an implementation and throws a build-timer error if they don't?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio 3.6.3 shows this error pop-up for me if I rename the `Java...boe` function to `xJava...boe`.
[image: Android Studio catches it]